# delete multiple lines in same cell excel (not a line break)

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a column of 2,000 numbers where there are 3 lines in the one cell and the information i need is in the lowest cell (as per b8) in sample below. In order for a lookup to work i need to put the cursor in front of first character of text on bottom row and key 'del' twice

I don't believe there are line breaks in this cell as cntl + j doesn't find anything as per screenprint. Could anyone kindly suggest a bulk way to delete these top 2 line please

Comment: IS it space or CHAR(255)? Alt+Enter?

Comment: You can use in a new column =Substitute(B8,CHAR(255),"") and drag it and when finish copy the new column paste special values where you need it

Comment: Hi, there are no spaces. Alt and enter does the opposite to what i'm try to do it, it creates a newline, though I cannot find any line breaks.

Comment: the char(255) suggestion kept on line 3 when I paste specialed.

Comment: It's `CHAR(13)`, most of the time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Find and replace` and in `Find what` just press `Ctrl` + `J` (you won't see anything but that's what you need) and replace it with empty or whatever you want.

Another thing that could be it is `CHAR(10)`, for that one hold `Alt` and press `0` then `1` then `0` and release `Alt`. Rest is the same.

Comment: I've tried this (and its worked for me before). I'm seeing the flashing dot in the find what box but when I search it it does not find a match. As per screenshot I pasted above. I've also tried re-opening my sheet as well. May need to close all excel sessions?

Comment: I edited my post because it could be `CHAR(10)` that is making you these troubles :)

Comment: To bring some closure tho this. I closed out of all excel sessions and tried the ctrl + j to find newlines and it worked.